# How to replace a key value with another list key value if different

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

```
# list_one 
state_a = [
    {
        'state': 'California',
        'city': 'LA',
        'region': 'W'
    },
    {
        'state': 'Texas',
        'city': 'Austin',
        'region': 'SW'
    }
]

# list_two
state_b = [
    {
        'state': 'Florida',
        'city': 'Miami',
        'region': 'SE'
    },
    {
        'state': 'Texas',
        'city': ['Austin', 'Houston'],
        'region': 'E'
    }
]
```

I would like some help on how can I find and replace the difference if the key values don't match. This is what I tried, but everything gets replaced. I only want to replace what's different from state_a.

```
result = []
for a in state_a:
    for b in state_b:
        if a['state'] == b['state']:
            result.append(a)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        'state': 'Texas', 
        'city': 'Austin', 
        'region': 'SW'
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        'state': 'Florida', 
        'city': 'Miami', 
        'region': 'SE'
    }, 
    {
        'state': 'Texas',
        'city': ['Austin', 'Houston'], 
        'region': 'SW' # only change in state_b to take effect
    }
]
```

As you can you, I only want this to affect what's different from both lists if the state name equals and make the change, but still keeping the other data.

Comment: what is the difference between `Expected` and `list_two`?

Comment: I'm just letting you know that `Expected` is the output I expect to get. That also has the correct values that I want `state_b (list_two)` to have.

Comment: What's state_a, state_b in your coding attempt?

Comment: Those are the lists. I made the modification above.

Comment: What's the reason the expected output has Florida but not California?

Comment: The reason is that I only want to make the change where there is a difference when the `state` equals. So, everything should be the same for `state_b` except that now the value for the key `region` will be replaced with that of `state_a` where `state = Texas`

Comment: In that case in the expected shouldn't the region be 'SW' since **"region will be replaced with that of state_a where state = Texas"**?

Comment: Whoops, Correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following produces expected output.

```
result = []
for b in state_b:
    result.append(b)                            # Add state from b
    for a in state_a:
        if a['state'] == result[-1]['state']:   # Check last state added
            result[-1]['region'] = a['region']  # Update region
            break
```

Comment: This works and I managed to get it that way. The problem with this is that if there are more keys where they don't equal to each other it won't work. Hardcoding `region` works fine in this case, not when there are more keys.

Comment: @arm65--is the case of your example both region and city (so two keys) did not equal, but you only wanted to update based upon region.  So, it seems even if multiple keys don't equal you only updated the value for one key of interest.  Could you clarify further?

Comment: I understand what you wrote. I think I explained it a bit too complicated. So, in the case where the `state` are equals if `state_a` key values is not in `state_b` key values, then I want to replace it. The key value for `city` in `state_a` is already in `state_b`. In that case the only thing different is the `region`.

Comment: @arm65--still not following.  You should update your question with an example that illustrates the problem.  You could use my code as code you have tried and show in your example the result not being the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (a, b) in zip(state_a, state_b):
    if a == b:
        result.append(a)
    if a != b:
        result.append(b)
```